# Increase yticks for two subplots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

i want to plot two graphs using subplot and increase yticks.

```
# Two subplots, the axes array is 1-d
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

ax[0].plot(df['Date'], df['Close'], label = 'S&P500 Close',linewidth = 3)
ax[0].set_ylabel('S&P500 Close')


ax[1].plot(df['Date'], df['VIX'],color='black',linewidth = 3)
ax[1].plot(df['Date'], df['Mean'], label = 'Durchschnitt',linewidth = 3)
ax[1].plot(df['Date'], df['BB_Oben'], linestyle='--', label = 'Oberes Band',linewidth = 3)
ax[1].plot(df['Date'], df['BB_Unten'],linestyle='--', label ='Unteres Band',linewidth = 3)
ax[1].set_ylabel('VIX')

plt.legend()
plt.xticks(fontsize = 18)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 18)
plt.show()
```

The `plt.yticks` only works for the lower graph and does not inrease yticks for the upper one. I also tried something like `ax[0].yticks(fontsize = 18)`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tick_params` feature to do this. Below is the example.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# We prepare the plot  
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)

# We change the fontsize of minor ticks label 
ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
ax[0].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)

ax[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=20)
ax[1].tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=20)
```

[image]